# msbuild Error MSB3411 Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"

Tags: msbuild, hudson

The Error is:

> ***C:_sourceCode\Project1\trunk\test\test.sln.cache(55,5): error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. ***

But I have the Microsoft Windows SDK and .Net Framework 3.5 and also Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.